# Wide table in twoside document

Tags: tables, double-sided, width

I am using a twoside document style and have a wide table crossing the right margin if it is on a right page. How can I disable the twoside style for just the table to center it. What is the correct way to solve this?
This is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\geometry{  a4paper,
            twoside,
            includemp,
            includehead,
            top = 30mm,
            headsep = 10mm,
            bindingoffset = 10mm,
            inner = 20mm,
            outer = 40mm,
            bottom = 45mm,
            marginparsep = 10mm,
            marginparwidth = 30mm
}
\savegeometry{myText}


\begin{document}
 aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo 

\begin{table}[hp]
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{3.5cm} p{5cm} }
\hline
\cline{1-2}
wiiiiide text \\
\hline
abcd  wide text     &  abcd  wide abcd  wide text           & abcd  wide text  abcd  wide text   \\
abcd                       & abcd  wide text            & abcd  wide text   &   \\
abcd                       & abcd           & abcd  &   \\
abcd           & abcd   &1     &  \\
abcd                   & abcd    & 1    &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\mbox{Looooooooong caption)}}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: does this solve your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode . I am genuinely curious how it's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the `tabular` (not `table`) inside a `\makebox` of pre-specified width. Then it doesn't matter how big the table is; LaTeX will see it as a box of that pre-specified width. The benefit from doing so is that you can adjust the alignment to suit your needs while not seeing any overfull `\hbox` warnings - common when working with "too long/wide content":

[image]

In the above output, the `tabular`s were set using

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{3.5cm} p{5cm} }
    \hline
    \cline{1-2}
    wiiiiide text \\
    \hline
    abcd  wide text &  abcd wide abcd  wide text & abcd  wide text  abcd  wide text   \\
    abcd            & abcd  wide text            & abcd  wide text                  & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & abcd                             & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}

\makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{3.5cm} p{5cm} }
    \hline
    \cline{1-2}
    wiiiiide text \\
    \hline
    abcd  wide text &  abcd wide abcd  wide text & abcd  wide text  abcd  wide text   \\
    abcd            & abcd  wide text            & abcd  wide text                  & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & abcd                             & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
    abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}
```

The first `\makebox` naturally centers its contents, while the latter is `r`ight-aligned.

---

Another option which includes adjusting the location of the `\caption` is possible via some help from [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth):

[image]

```
\begin{table}[hp]
  \makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\paperwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{3.5cm} p{5cm} }
      \hline
      \cline{1-2}
      wiiiiide text \\
      \hline
      abcd  wide text &  abcd wide abcd  wide text & abcd  wide text  abcd  wide text   \\
      abcd            & abcd  wide text            & abcd  wide text                  & \\
      abcd            & abcd                       & abcd                             & \\
      abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
      abcd            & abcd                       & 1                                & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{\mbox{Looooooooong caption)}}
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Great! The caption is still indented though?

Comment: @RootRaven: See the updated answer. This still right-aligns the `table` to the text block, but allows it to extend into the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

Cosidering that your table appears to be *far wider* than the text block, it may not be possible to place the table on a page alongside regular text in an aesthetically pleasing manner. You may therefore want to look into using the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment, to place the table rotated 90 degrees on a page by itself. I.e., load the `rotating` package in the preamble and use `\begin{sidewaystable}` and `\end{sidewaystable} instead of`\begin{table}[hp]`and`\end{table}. (Since material in a sidewaystable environment is necessarily set on a separate page, there's no point in providing the `[h]` location specifiier.)

Comment: I think this looks fine. Here an example where full width figures and tables where used in a twoside style thesis: http://hci.rwth-aachen.de/materials/publications/kurz2013a.pdf

Comment: @RootRaven - An interesting (appealing!) layout. The page setup in the link you provide is fairly different from the one of your MWE. The "gutters" (where the callouts appear) are nice and wide, and tables and figures are then allowed to take up the combined width of the text block and the gutter.