# How to solve longtable is not in 1-column mode error?

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to compile a document with the example code for longtable but I
get an error saying that longtable is not in 1-column mode. Suggest me the correct way?

Comment: Don't use longtable in twocolumn.

Comment: On the other hand, you can use `supertabular` in two column.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`longtable` doesn't work well with `twocolumn`. But you can use `supertabular`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}

\tablefirsthead{\toprule First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} \\ \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous column}} \\
\toprule
First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{supertabular}{ll}
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes here too \\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text
\end{supertabular}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by egreg, `xtab` is another choice. `xtab` is built on `supertabular` while avoiding its weaknesses.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}
\topcaption{This is top caption}
\bottomcaption{This is bottom caption}
\tablecaption{this is table caption}
\tablefirsthead{\toprule First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} \\ \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous column}} \\
\toprule
First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{%
\midrule \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next column}} \\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{ll}
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes here too \\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text
\end{xtabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or maybe `xtab` that's based on `supertabular`, but it's supposed to enhance it.

Comment: @egreg Could you please tell me how to replace `Continued on next column` with , for example, `continue Table 1` where the table number refers to the respective table?

Answer (score 25):

If you still want to stick to longtable (e.g. because you are generating LaTeX through pandoc) you could redefine the `\longtable` command.

A possible solution is this one:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldlt\longtable
\let\endoldlt\endlongtable
\def\longtable{\@ifnextchar[\longtable@i \longtable@ii}
\def\longtable@i[#1]{\begin{figure}[t]
\onecolumn
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\oldlt[#1]
}
\def\longtable@ii{\begin{figure}[t]
\onecolumn
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\oldlt
}
\def\endlongtable{\endoldlt
\end{minipage}
\twocolumn
\end{figure}}
\makeatother
```

**NB**: it works with two columns, which is what you'll find very often in journal article document classes.

To use this fragment with pandoc, you can e.g. use the [-H switch](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#general-writer-options) which lets you include some additional code before your actual content. Just create a file called `preamble.tex` and insert the code above. You can then run `pandoc -H preamble.tex` and the code will automatically be included.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! The snippet works when added *after* the packages are used.

Comment: You are a life saver thank you! I also added this line `\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}` to the snippet to make the table caption span over the line without exceeding it.

Comment: How would you modify this to allow a `longtable*` environment where the table's width spans both columns (e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode))?

Comment: Does this also work with `longtabu`?

Answer (score 15):

Another option, not covered in the previous answers, is to force single column mode along with a `\clearpage` before your longtable and then reset it to two column mode after. This would look like:

```
\clearpage
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}
...
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
\twocolumn
```

This is potentially more useful than the previous examples as it doesn't require rebuilding much, and has the added bonus of working in platforms like arXiv.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of [Huan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/171573/huan) and others: for [hellobenallans answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425198/157211) to work you must first include `\usepackage{xtab}` in your header.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Normally, comments belong in the comments section, but I think you can't comment with too little reputation. I added a link to your answer in the comments of the answer you commented.

Comment: Thanks @thymaro, it was indeed the case that I didn't have enough reputation to post a proper comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck trying to use multiple columns with pandoc, and similar to [Marco Torchiano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224096/33862) I redefined  the `longtable` environment  in a preamble, but in my case I redefined it to use the `xtabular` environment.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Redefine longtable because it doesn't work in multicolumn
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\def\longtable{\@ifnextchar[\newlongtable@i \newlongtable@ii}
\def\newlongtable@i[#1]{%
\renewcommand{\endhead}{\ignorespaces}
\xtabular[#1]}
\def\newlongtable@ii{%
\renewcommand{\endhead}{\ignorespaces}
\xtabular}
\def\endlongtable{\endxtabular}
\makeatother
```

The code above isn't the prettiest, but seems to work all right when I call pandoc using the `--include-in-header` (or `-H`) option:

```
pandoc                                    \
  --standalone                            \
  --from=markdown                         \
  --template=pandoc-template.tex          \
  --include-in-header=pandoc-preamble.tex \
  --pdf-engine=xelatex                    \
  -o out.pdf                              \
  in.md
```

This can produce a pdf which contains tables in a two-column layout, apparently without issue.

Comment: I got a `Error producing PDF. ! Undefined control sequence. \newlongtable@i ...ad }{\ignorespaces } \xtabular [#1] l.138 \begin{longtable}[]`

Comment: Apparently, you need to add `xtab`. See [this comment-anwer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547894/117274).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: it can be used in twocolumn documents.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Long Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, hlines,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
  row{1-2,Z} = {font=\bfseries},
}
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\end{longtblr}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this page looking to fix the issue with **pandoc** using `longtable` in `twocolumn` mode.  I had use the `supertabular` fix above last year and it worked, but with some updates this year it was giving a `\noalign` error that I could not sort out.

Putting the code below (which replaces `longtable` with `tabular`) in the preamble fixed my issues (and I do not actually want multi-page tables, so this is a fine change for me).

```
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}}{\end{tabular}\end{center}}
\renewcommand{\endhead}{}
\renewcommand{\toprule}[2]{\hline}
\renewcommand{\midrule}[2]{\hline}
\renewcommand{\bottomrule}[2]{\hline}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [Marcos Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224096/168892) with longtable for acronyms, one might change the figures to be displayed "here" (`[t]->[h]`), and therefore at the `\printacronyms` command.

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldlt\longtable
\let\endoldlt\endlongtable
\def\longtable{\@ifnextchar[\longtable@i \longtable@ii}
\def\longtable@i[#1]{\begin{figure}[h]
  \onecolumn
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \oldlt[#1]
    }
\def\longtable@ii{\begin{figure}[h]
  \onecolumn
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \oldlt
    }
\def\endlongtable{\endoldlt
  \end{minipage}
  \twocolumn
\end{figure}}
\makeatother
```