# How to split long table into two columns ?

Tags: longtable

I have a table which is very long, so I have used long table to split it across multiple pages, now that still it is spanning many pages, I want to further split the table into two columns in each page.

My table is as follows :

```
\begingroup
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Left Eye}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Right Eye}}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(r){6-7}
\textbf{Subject} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\
\midrule
S005\_001\_00000001     &&  308 &   200 &&  431 &   196 \\
S005\_001\_00000011     &&  299 &   199 &&  439 &   193 \\
S010\_002\_00000001     &&  312 &   224 &&  436 &   222 \\
S010\_002\_00000014     &&  316 &   219 &&  437 &   217 \\
S010\_004\_00000001     &&  310 &   224 &&  433 &   220 \\
S010\_004\_00000019     &&  313 &   225 &&  432 &   220 \\
S010\_006\_00000001     &&  312 &   223 &&  435 &   217 \\
S010\_006\_00000015     &&  312 &   219 &&  434 &   213 \\
S011\_001\_00000001     &&  337 &   224 &&  444 &   217 \\
S011\_001\_00000016     &&  331 &   221 &&  448 &   213 \\
S011\_002\_00000001     &&  333 &   224 &&  451 &   215 \\
S011\_002\_00000022     &&  335 &   228 &&  452 &   219 \\
S011\_003\_00000001     &&  330 &   222 &&  447 &   216 \\
S011\_003\_00000014     &&  325 &   214 &&  443 &   207 \\
S011\_004\_00000001     &&  330 &   222 &&  448 &   216 \\
S011\_004\_00000021     &&  332 &   230 &&  451 &   224 \\
S011\_005\_00000001     &&  328 &   224 &&  446 &   217 \\
S011\_005\_00000020     &&  327 &   227 &&  450 &   222 \\
S011\_006\_00000001     &&  332 &   223 &&  450 &   216 \\
S011\_006\_00000013     &&  334 &   224 &&  453 &   217 \\
S014\_001\_00000001     &&  304 &   235 &&  426 &   231 \\
S014\_001\_00000029     &&  309 &   233 &&  429 &   228 \\
S014\_002\_00000001     &&  305 &   237 &&  425 &   231 \\
S014\_002\_00000016     &&  305 &   242 &&  426 &   235 \\
S014\_003\_00000001     &&  304 &   238 &&  426 &   234 \\
S014\_003\_00000030     &&  306 &   238 &&  427 &   233 \\
S014\_005\_00000001     &&  306 &   234 &&  428 &   229 \\
S014\_005\_00000017     &&  310 &   233 &&  430 &   227 \\
S022\_001\_00000001     &&  300 &   200 &&  388 &   194 \\
S022\_001\_00000030     &&  297 &   193 &&  384 &   187 \\
S022\_005\_00000001     &&  304 &   195 &&  392 &   191 \\
S022\_005\_00000032     &&  304 &   200 &&  392 &   194 \\
S022\_006\_00000001     &&  299 &   198 &&  387 &   192 \\
S022\_006\_00000017     &&  297 &   196 &&  388 &   191 \\
S026\_001\_00000001     &&  286 &   211 &&  378 &   207 \\
S026\_001\_00000015     &&  292 &   192 &&  382 &   187 \\
S026\_002\_00000001     &&  284 &   210 &&  376 &   205 \\
S026\_002\_00000016     &&  286 &   209 &&  377 &   205 \\
S026\_003\_00000001     &&  286 &   206 &&  378 &   202 \\
S026\_003\_00000015     &&  287 &   213 &&  378 &   208 \\
S026\_006\_00000001     &&  289 &   209 &&  382 &   205 \\
S026\_006\_00000013     &&  287 &   206 &&  379 &   202 \\
S028\_001\_00000001     &&  308 &   243 &&  396 &   241 \\
S028\_001\_00000024     &&  308 &   244 &&  396 &   242 \\
S029\_001\_00000001     &&  273 &   203 &&  369 &   201 \\
S029\_001\_00000019     &&  273 &   207 &&  368 &   203 \\
S032\_001\_00000001     &&  299 &   218 &&  381 &   218 \\
S032\_001\_00000022     &&  298 &   206 &&  376 &   206 \\
S032\_003\_00000001     &&  303 &   215 &&  385 &   217 \\
S032\_003\_00000017     &&  302 &   221 &&  381 &   223 \\
S032\_004\_00000001     &&  304 &   215 &&  386 &   216 \\
S032\_004\_00000014     &&  302 &   216 &&  382 &   217 \\
S032\_005\_00000001     &&  300 &   217 &&  382 &   218 \\
S032\_005\_00000016     &&  297 &   219 &&  383 &   221 \\
S032\_006\_00000001     &&  301 &   214 &&  383 &   212 \\
S032\_006\_00000016     &&  302 &   215 &&  381 &   216 \\
S034\_001\_00000001     &&  253 &   229 &&  339 &   226 \\
S034\_001\_00000029     &&  251 &   225 &&  338 &   223 \\
S034\_003\_00000001     &&  256 &   229 &&  342 &   227 \\
S034\_003\_00000027     &&  258 &   229 &&  343 &   228 \\
S034\_005\_00000001     &&  253 &   228 &&  340 &   226 \\
S034\_005\_00000010     &&  252 &   227 &&  340 &   224 \\
S035\_001\_00000001     &&  258 &   219 &&  343 &   220 \\
S035\_001\_00000015     &&  262 &   213 &&  346 &   211 \\
S035\_005\_00000001     &&  262 &   218 &&  347 &   217 \\
S035\_005\_00000019     &&  260 &   219 &&  346 &   216 \\
S035\_006\_00000001     &&  262 &   220 &&  344 &   218 \\
S035\_006\_00000018     &&  266 &   220 &&  349 &   219 \\
S037\_001\_00000001     &&  309 &   201 &&  392 &   203 \\
S037\_001\_00000020     &&  313 &   211 &&  400 &   214 \\
S037\_003\_00000001     &&  312 &   205 &&  396 &   207 \\
S037\_003\_00000022     &&  312 &   211 &&  398 &   211 \\
S037\_006\_00000001     &&  312 &   199 &&  396 &   198 \\
S037\_006\_00000021     &&  317 &   196 &&  399 &   196 \\
S042\_001\_00000001     &&  295 &   231 &&  378 &   233 \\
S042\_001\_00000019     &&  293 &   226 &&  379 &   227 \\
S042\_002\_00000001     &&  293 &   230 &&  378 &   232 \\
S042\_002\_00000016     &&  292 &   232 &&  379 &   232 \\
S042\_004\_00000001     &&  294 &   230 &&  377 &   232 \\
S042\_004\_00000020     &&  291 &   230 &&  377 &   231 \\
S042\_006\_00000001     &&  294 &   233 &&  379 &   233 \\
S042\_006\_00000017     &&  294 &   229 &&  378 &   232 \\
S044\_001\_00000001     &&  308 &   220 &&  385 &   224 \\
S044\_001\_00000024     &&  308 &   220 &&  385 &   222 \\
S044\_003\_00000014     &&  310 &   222 &&  385 &   226 \\
S044\_006\_00000019     &&  306 &   222 &&  387 &   226 \\
S045\_004\_00000001     &&  251 &   229 &&  338 &   227 \\
S045\_004\_00000015     &&  250 &   231 &&  342 &   226 \\
S045\_005\_00000030     &&  243 &   238 &&  327 &   233 \\
S046\_001\_00000001     &&  262 &   212 &&  354 &   206 \\
S046\_001\_00000025     &&  258 &   212 &&  349 &   205 \\
S046\_002\_00000006     &&  264 &   202 &&  355 &   197 \\
S046\_003\_00000016     &&  265 &   205 &&  355 &   201 \\
S046\_004\_00000017     &&  265 &   214 &&  355 &   207 \\
S050\_001\_00000001     &&  365 &   205 &&  451 &   203 \\
S050\_001\_00000017     &&  370 &   198 &&  454 &   196 \\
S050\_002\_00000018     &&  367 &   181 &&  451 &   181 \\
S050\_004\_00000021     &&  365 &   206 &&  448 &   204 \\
S050\_006\_00000023     &&  371 &   196 &&  454 &   196 \\
S051\_002\_00000001     &&  222 &   230 &&  335 &   225 \\
S051\_002\_00000019     &&  222 &   187 &&  332 &   183 \\
S051\_003\_00000018     &&  241 &   245 &&  349 &   230 \\
S052\_001\_00000001     &&  271 &   211 &&  375 &   215 \\
S052\_001\_00000015     &&  273 &   206 &&  376 &   208 \\
S052\_004\_00000033     &&  268 &   219 &&  371 &   220 \\
S052\_006\_00000013     &&  273 &   211 &&  375 &   214 \\
S053\_001\_00000001     &&  260 &   214 &&  381 &   210 \\
S053\_001\_00000023     &&  258 &   200 &&  382 &   196 \\
S053\_004\_00000024     &&  256 &   210 &&  378 &   201 \\
S054\_002\_00000001     &&  271 &   239 &&  375 &   235 \\
S054\_002\_00000015     &&  274 &   241 &&  380 &   241 \\
S054\_003\_00000007     &&  268 &   237 &&  374 &   234 \\
S054\_004\_00000024     &&  272 &   249 &&  382 &   247 \\
S055\_001\_00000001     &&  309 &   228 &&  409 &   231 \\
S055\_001\_00000012     &&  314 &   223 &&  413 &   225 \\
S055\_003\_00000009     &&  307 &   227 &&  408 &   230 \\
S055\_004\_00000028     &&  314 &   239 &&  413 &   242 \\
S055\_005\_00000045     &&  309 &   227 &&  408 &   238 \\
S055\_006\_00000008     &&  309 &   230 &&  408 &   233 \\
S056\_002\_00000001     &&  241 &   222 &&  340 &   222 \\
S056\_002\_00000010     &&  241 &   221 &&  339 &   221 \\
S056\_003\_00000010     &&  242 &   204 &&  340 &   202 \\
S056\_004\_00000020     &&  237 &   211 &&  334 &   209 \\
S057\_001\_00000001     &&  277 &   211 &&  385 &   204 \\
S057\_001\_00000019     &&  278 &   208 &&  385 &   201 \\
S057\_003\_00000015     &&  277 &   211 &&  384 &   204 \\
S057\_006\_00000033     &&  274 &   206 &&  381 &   200 \\
S058\_001\_00000001     &&  272 &   199 &&  379 &   197 \\
S058\_001\_00000020     &&  270 &   193 &&  379 &   191 \\
S058\_005\_00000010     &&  274 &   198 &&  381 &   198 \\
S058\_006\_00000018     &&  271 &   199 &&  385 &   199 \\
S059\_001\_00000001     &&  312 &   219 &&  417 &   221 \\
S059\_001\_00000018     &&  317 &   215 &&  422 &   219 \\
S059\_002\_00000017     &&  314 &   211 &&  418 &   214 \\
S060\_002\_00000001     &&  278 &   234 &&  384 &   241 \\
S060\_002\_00000026     &&  282 &   238 &&  388 &   243 \\
S060\_003\_00000018     &&  276 &   220 &&  383 &   223 \\
S060\_005\_00000021     &&  278 &   249 &&  389 &   248 \\
S061\_001\_00000001     &&  286 &   234 &&  391 &   241 \\
S061\_001\_00000012     &&  286 &   235 &&  389 &   241 \\
S061\_002\_00000015     &&  286 &   234 &&  389 &   240 \\
S061\_004\_00000022     &&  284 &   234 &&  389 &   240 \\
S062\_001\_00000001     &&  227 &   232 &&  348 &   217 \\
S062\_001\_00000017     &&  225 &   232 &&  347 &   219 \\
S062\_002\_00000016     &&  227 &   224 &&  347 &   210 \\
S062\_004\_00000024     &&  228 &   232 &&  348 &   218 \\
S062\_005\_00000029     &&  221 &   233 &&  339 &   216 \\
S063\_001\_00000001     &&  242 &   213 &&  351 &   203 \\
S063\_001\_00000013     &&  240 &   201 &&  350 &   189 \\
S063\_002\_00000023     &&  243 &   211 &&  351 &   204 \\
S064\_001\_00000001     &&  242 &   187 &&  341 &   187 \\
S064\_001\_00000012     &&  244 &   180 &&  343 &   181 \\
S064\_003\_00000025     &&  246 &   169 &&  345 &   172 \\
S064\_004\_00000014     &&  245 &   188 &&  344 &   189 \\
S065\_002\_00000001     &&  252 &   210 &&  345 &   210 \\
S065\_002\_00000022     &&  255 &   208 &&  349 &   210 \\
S065\_003\_00000022     &&  248 &   204 &&  344 &   204 \\
S065\_004\_00000028     &&  253 &   217 &&  346 &   216 \\
S065\_005\_00000008     &&  253 &   224 &&  347 &   227 \\
S066\_002\_00000001     &&  292 &   209 &&  398 &   208 \\
S066\_002\_00000022     &&  293 &   206 &&  398 &   204 \\
S066\_003\_00000012     &&  291 &   215 &&  396 &   214 \\
S066\_004\_00000010     &&  297 &   211 &&  402 &   210 \\
S066\_005\_00000011     &&  294 &   215 &&  397 &   215 \\
S067\_002\_00000001     &&  278 &   222 &&  386 &   219 \\
S067\_002\_00000014     &&  270 &   222 &&  376 &   217 \\
S067\_004\_00000023     &&  279 &   240 &&  386 &   236 \\
S067\_005\_00000022     &&  274 &   228 &&  380 &   222 \\
S067\_006\_00000011     &&  272 &   222 &&  378 &   217 \\
S068\_002\_00000001     &&  218 &   232 &&  319 &   235 \\
S068\_002\_00000015     &&  219 &   231 &&  317 &   234 \\
S068\_003\_00000014     &&  210 &   228 &&  310 &   228 \\
S068\_004\_00000010     &&  214 &   232 &&  312 &   233 \\
S068\_005\_00000021     &&  213 &   234 &&  310 &   232 \\
S069\_002\_00000001     &&  254 &   242 &&  363 &   234 \\
S069\_002\_00000014     &&  253 &   233 &&  361 &   225 \\
S069\_003\_00000011     &&  255 &   242 &&  368 &   234 \\
S069\_004\_00000017     &&  251 &   237 &&  364 &   230 \\
S070\_002\_00000001     &&  286 &   210 &&  385 &   211 \\
S070\_002\_00000016     &&  286 &   208 &&  386 &   208 \\
S070\_003\_00000017     &&  286 &   212 &&  385 &   213 \\
S070\_005\_00000016     &&  285 &   212 &&  386 &   214 \\
S071\_001\_00000001     &&  291 &   179 &&  395 &   184 \\
S071\_001\_00000013     &&  292 &   177 &&  396 &   183 \\
S071\_002\_00000020     &&  293 &   179 &&  394 &   182 \\
S071\_004\_00000028     &&  292 &   185 &&  395 &   187 \\
S071\_005\_00000021     &&  287 &   179 &&  392 &   183 \\
S071\_006\_00000014     &&  287 &   179 &&  394 &   184 \\
S072\_005\_00000001     &&  284 &   231 &&  385 &   230 \\
S072\_005\_00000019     &&  289 &   248 &&  389 &   248 \\
S072\_006\_00000022     &&  284 &   230 &&  385 &   229 \\
S073\_001\_00000001     &&  250 &   212 &&  363 &   211 \\
S073\_001\_00000013     &&  250 &   204 &&  362 &   204 \\
S073\_006\_00000014     &&  248 &   217 &&  360 &   212 \\
S074\_001\_00000001     &&  247 &   231 &&  348 &   234 \\
S074\_001\_00000020     &&  246 &   229 &&  346 &   232 \\
S074\_002\_00000016     &&  251 &   224 &&  349 &   226 \\
S074\_004\_00000018     &&  246 &   234 &&  349 &   235 \\
S074\_005\_00000043     &&  247 &   232 &&  349 &   234 \\
S075\_002\_00000001     &&  241 &   226 &&  355 &   231 \\
S075\_002\_00000014     &&  242 &   214 &&  354 &   217 \\
S075\_005\_00000012     &&  240 &   227 &&  354 &   233 \\
S075\_006\_00000025     &&  243 &   225 &&  355 &   229 \\
S075\_008\_00000012     &&  246 &   213 &&  357 &   218 \\
S076\_001\_00000001     &&  254 &   221 &&  365 &   220 \\
S076\_001\_00000017     &&  252 &   209 &&  365 &   211 \\
S076\_005\_00000012     &&  252 &   223 &&  363 &   223 \\
S076\_006\_00000019     &&  259 &   218 &&  371 &   221 \\
S077\_001\_00000001     &&  262 &   169 &&  362 &   166 \\
S077\_001\_00000028     &&  263 &   163 &&  362 &   163 \\
S077\_006\_00000014     &&  265 &   170 &&  365 &   168 \\
S078\_001\_00000001     &&  261 &   207 &&  358 &   206 \\
S078\_001\_00000033     &&  260 &   204 &&  358 &   203 \\
S078\_004\_00000027     &&  259 &   206 &&  355 &   203 \\
S078\_007\_00000013     &&  259 &   207 &&  356 &   206 \\
S079\_001\_00000001     &&  223 &   223 &&  335 &   221 \\
S079\_001\_00000012     &&  223 &   218 &&  336 &   215 \\
S079\_002\_00000012     &&  222 &   225 &&  336 &   223 \\
S079\_004\_00000026     &&  222 &   218 &&  333 &   213 \\
S080\_001\_00000001     &&  258 &   202 &&  368 &   196 \\
S080\_001\_00000018     &&  262 &   189 &&  365 &   183 \\
S080\_005\_00000013     &&  258 &   200 &&  359 &   189 \\
S080\_008\_00000009     &&  263 &   198 &&  365 &   193 \\
S081\_001\_00000001     &&  275 &   185 &&  380 &   190 \\
S081\_001\_00000019     &&  273 &   202 &&  379 &   205 \\
S081\_002\_00000024     &&  272 &   188 &&  378 &   192 \\
S081\_008\_00000011     &&  272 &   187 &&  381 &   191 \\
S082\_001\_00000001     &&  270 &   199 &&  371 &   196 \\
S082\_001\_00000015     &&  273 &   180 &&  374 &   179 \\
S082\_005\_00000017     &&  273 &   202 &&  375 &   201 \\
S083\_003\_00000001     &&  236 &   210 &&  348 &   213 \\
S083\_003\_00000019     &&  235 &   210 &&  348 &   215 \\
S084\_001\_00000001     &&  260 &   172 &&  358 &   172 \\
S084\_001\_00000010     &&  257 &   169 &&  356 &   167 \\
S084\_002\_00000023     &&  250 &   173 &&  349 &   169 \\
S085\_002\_00000001     &&  251 &   175 &&  349 &   176 \\
S085\_002\_00000014     &&  252 &   173 &&  349 &   176 \\
S085\_003\_00000013     &&  258 &   154 &&  358 &   153 \\
S085\_004\_00000017     &&  252 &   173 &&  350 &   175 \\
S086\_001\_00000001     &&  219 &   167 &&  317 &   170 \\
S086\_001\_00000019     &&  216 &   158 &&  316 &   159 \\
S086\_002\_00000015     &&  216 &   172 &&  316 &   172 \\
S087\_001\_00000001     &&  244 &   157 &&  348 &   157 \\
S087\_001\_00000011     &&  247 &   137 &&  347 &   138 \\
S087\_004\_00000012     &&  242 &   159 &&  347 &   159 \\
S087\_005\_00000012     &&  248 &   148 &&  352 &   147 \\
S087\_007\_00000016     &&  253 &   151 &&  356 &   154 \\
S088\_001\_00000001     &&  222 &   214 &&  329 &   207 \\
S088\_001\_00000017     &&  222 &   215 &&  330 &   207 \\
S088\_004\_00000020     &&  216 &   213 &&  328 &   207 \\
S089\_001\_00000001     &&  227 &   186 &&  332 &   183 \\
S089\_001\_00000016     &&  224 &   171 &&  328 &   168 \\
S089\_002\_00000021     &&  231 &   186 &&  333 &   183 \\
S089\_003\_00000036     &&  225 &   198 &&  338 &   195 \\
S090\_002\_00000001     &&  251 &   141 &&  358 &   138 \\
S090\_002\_00000011     &&  248 &   136 &&  358 &   136 \\
S090\_006\_00000011     &&  249 &   143 &&  357 &   141 \\
S090\_007\_00000014     &&  245 &   143 &&  356 &   140 \\
S091\_001\_00000001     &&  212 &   163 &&  320 &   162 \\
S091\_001\_00000015     &&  209 &   161 &&  320 &   161 \\
S091\_003\_00000021     &&  211 &   172 &&  317 &   169 \\
S092\_001\_00000001     &&  237 &   213 &&  340 &   205 \\
S092\_001\_00000017     &&  235 &   198 &&  336 &   193 \\
S092\_003\_00000014     &&  243 &   215 &&  344 &   209 \\
S092\_004\_00000024     &&  242 &   212 &&  342 &   206 \\
S093\_001\_00000001     &&  247 &   148 &&  350 &   148 \\
S093\_001\_00000020     &&  241 &   153 &&  346 &   152 \\
S093\_004\_00000016     &&  251 &   145 &&  354 &   142 \\
S094\_001\_00000001     &&  256 &   163 &&  357 &   166 \\
S094\_001\_00000010     &&  252 &   162 &&  352 &   164 \\
S094\_004\_00000012     &&  252 &   166 &&  352 &   167 \\
S095\_001\_00000001     &&  268 &   174 &&  373 &   183 \\
S095\_001\_00000016     &&  268 &   175 &&  372 &   182 \\
S095\_006\_00000013     &&  266 &   177 &&  373 &   184 \\
S095\_007\_00000021     &&  273 &   175 &&  377 &   183 \\
S095\_010\_00000014     &&  271 &   182 &&  372 &   190 \\
S096\_001\_00000001     &&  256 &   198 &&  360 &   189 \\
S096\_001\_00000007     &&  256 &   192 &&  361 &   183 \\
S096\_003\_00000012     &&  254 &   197 &&  358 &   187 \\
S096\_004\_00000011     &&  257 &   196 &&  362 &   187 \\
S097\_001\_00000001     &&  259 &   163 &&  363 &   168 \\
S097\_001\_00000021     &&  260 &   144 &&  367 &   150 \\
S097\_004\_00000030     &&  259 &   168 &&  363 &   168 \\
S097\_006\_00000019     &&  261 &   162 &&  364 &   166 \\
S098\_003\_00000001     &&  212 &   177 &&  319 &   178 \\
S098\_003\_00000013     &&  212 &   179 &&  321 &   178 \\
S098\_004\_00000015     &&  213 &   171 &&  320 &   173 \\
S099\_001\_00000001     &&  244 &   183 &&  346 &   181 \\
S099\_001\_00000014     &&  243 &   170 &&  344 &   167 \\
S099\_004\_00000015     &&  243 &   167 &&  346 &   165 \\
S099\_007\_00000012     &&  239 &   186 &&  352 &   183 \\
S100\_002\_00000001     &&  247 &   174 &&  361 &   178 \\
S100\_002\_00000015     &&  245 &   172 &&  356 &   174 \\
S100\_005\_00000023     &&  250 &   178 &&  362 &   182 \\
S100\_006\_00000016     &&  249 &   171 &&  363 &   177 \\
S101\_002\_00000001     &&  265 &   183 &&  367 &   184 \\
S101\_002\_00000019     &&  272 &   162 &&  372 &   163 \\
S102\_002\_00000001     &&  273 &   148 &&  365 &   150 \\
S102\_002\_00000018     &&  269 &   137 &&  361 &   140 \\
S102\_003\_00000016     &&  266 &   151 &&  360 &   156 \\
S102\_009\_00000015     &&  282 &   145 &&  368 &   149 \\
S105\_008\_00000001     &&  242 &   165 &&  343 &   161 \\
S105\_008\_00000010     &&  243 &   167 &&  342 &   162 \\
S106\_002\_00000001     &&  250 &   185 &&  356 &   182 \\
S106\_002\_00000016     &&  252 &   196 &&  359 &   193 \\
S106\_004\_00000008     &&  243 &   189 &&  358 &   187 \\
S106\_006\_00000011     &&  245 &   179 &&  357 &   181 \\
S107\_001\_00000001     &&  252 &   228 &&  356 &   227 \\
S107\_001\_00000010     &&  254 &   205 &&  358 &   207 \\
S107\_005\_00000011     &&  251 &   236 &&  364 &   235 \\
S108\_005\_00000001     &&  292 &   206 &&  385 &   205 \\
S108\_005\_00000022     &&  289 &   219 &&  381 &   212 \\
S108\_006\_00000020     &&  290 &   206 &&  383 &   203 \\
S108\_008\_00000013     &&  289 &   202 &&  385 &   200 \\
S109\_003\_00000001     &&  246 &   186 &&  342 &   183 \\
S109\_003\_00000017     &&  245 &   190 &&  344 &   189 \\
S109\_005\_00000014     &&  244 &   185 &&  341 &   183 \\
S109\_006\_00000015     &&  246 &   187 &&  342 &   187 \\
S110\_001\_00000001     &&  271 &   200 &&  368 &   199 \\
S110\_001\_00000013     &&  267 &   183 &&  365 &   178 \\
S111\_001\_00000001     &&  256 &   186 &&  354 &   178 \\
S111\_001\_00000014     &&  255 &   174 &&  351 &   168 \\
S111\_006\_00000010     &&  253 &   186 &&  349 &   180 \\
S111\_007\_00000014     &&  252 &   184 &&  349 &   177 \\
S112\_005\_00000001     &&  288 &   175 &&  389 &   173 \\
S112\_005\_00000017     &&  283 &   180 &&  387 &   177 \\
S113\_001\_00000001     &&  248 &   185 &&  357 &   183 \\
S113\_001\_00000012     &&  248 &   177 &&  355 &   177 \\
S113\_003\_00000015     &&  244 &   188 &&  353 &   185 \\
S113\_008\_00000023     &&  245 &   188 &&  351 &   185 \\
S114\_001\_00000001     &&  244 &   213 &&  348 &   211 \\
S114\_001\_00000018     &&  249 &   189 &&  352 &   188 \\
S114\_006\_00000023     &&  244 &   204 &&  347 &   201 \\
S115\_001\_00000001     &&  253 &   195 &&  357 &   189 \\
S115\_001\_00000008     &&  255 &   187 &&  359 &   181 \\
S115\_004\_00000017     &&  236 &   199 &&  339 &   193 \\
S115\_008\_00000017     &&  255 &   198 &&  358 &   192 \\
S116\_001\_00000001     &&  238 &   194 &&  336 &   192 \\
S116\_001\_00000014     &&  237 &   183 &&  336 &   180 \\
S116\_006\_00000007     &&  233 &   199 &&  339 &   195 \\
S116\_007\_00000017     &&  238 &   194 &&  336 &   192 \\
S117\_001\_00000001     &&  259 &   179 &&  355 &   177 \\
S117\_001\_00000014     &&  264 &   163 &&  360 &   162 \\
S117\_003\_00000014     &&  253 &   168 &&  346 &   168 \\
S117\_006\_00000010     &&  252 &   179 &&  348 &   197 \\
S119\_001\_00000001     &&  260 &   190 &&  357 &   184 \\
S119\_001\_00000011     &&  257 &   172 &&  355 &   168 \\
S119\_003\_00000024     &&  246 &   177 &&  344 &   172 \\
S119\_008\_00000018     &&  257 &   204 &&  352 &   193 \\
S122\_001\_00000001     &&  216 &   201 &&  324 &   204 \\
S122\_001\_00000012     &&  218 &   197 &&  324 &   201 \\
S124\_001\_00000001     &&  214 &   201 &&  302 &   191 \\
S124\_001\_00000014     &&  208 &   176 &&  297 &   170 \\
S124\_003\_00000011     &&  215 &   193 &&  302 &   185 \\
S124\_006\_00000011     &&  213 &   193 &&  302 &   188 \\
S124\_007\_00000024     &&  228 &   181 &&  317 &   181 \\
S125\_001\_00000001     &&  285 &   207 &&  383 &   208 \\
S125\_001\_00000014     &&  285 &   210 &&  383 &   212 \\
S125\_005\_00000013     &&  286 &   205 &&  387 &   207 \\
S125\_006\_00000022     &&  285 &   202 &&  383 &   203 \\
S125\_007\_00000009     &&  282 &   202 &&  383 &   203 \\
S125\_008\_00000010     &&  282 &   207 &&  385 &   209 \\
S126\_004\_00000001     &&  227 &   200 &&  336 &   197 \\
S126\_004\_00000012     &&  229 &   194 &&  339 &   191 \\
S126\_008\_00000029     &&  228 &   207 &&  335 &   205 \\
S127\_001\_00000001     &&  264 &   230 &&  360 &   222 \\
S127\_001\_00000017     &&  263 &   218 &&  361 &   210 \\
S127\_004\_00000016     &&  266 &   226 &&  362 &   222 \\
S127\_010\_00000018     &&  267 &   233 &&  365 &   227 \\
S128\_004\_00000001     &&  217 &   225 &&  312 &   221 \\
S128\_004\_00000013     &&  217 &   227 &&  312 &   222 \\
S128\_011\_00000016     &&  225 &   223 &&  318 &   219 \\
S129\_002\_00000001     &&  237 &   210 &&  334 &   207 \\
S129\_002\_00000011     &&  238 &   211 &&  334 &   208 \\
S129\_006\_00000010     &&  240 &   223 &&  341 &   224 \\
S129\_011\_00000018     &&  240 &   225 &&  341 &   225 \\
S129\_012\_00000011     &&  241 &   223 &&  340 &   221 \\
S130\_001\_00000001     &&  232 &   221 &&  337 &   226 \\
S130\_001\_00000018     &&  232 &   218 &&  339 &   223 \\
S130\_007\_00000020     &&  230 &   225 &&  337 &   227 \\
S130\_009\_00000019     &&  231 &   223 &&  336 &   229 \\
S130\_012\_00000011     &&  229 &   223 &&  337 &   230 \\
S130\_013\_00000015     &&  227 &   219 &&  335 &   225 \\
S131\_001\_00000001     &&  270 &   188 &&  375 &   186 \\
S131\_001\_00000016     &&  270 &   169 &&  374 &   168 \\
S131\_003\_00000024     &&  275 &   203 &&  378 &   199 \\
S131\_006\_00000022     &&  268 &   193 &&  371 &   187 \\
S131\_010\_00000018     &&  268 &   203 &&  370 &   198 \\
S132\_002\_00000001     &&  265 &   200 &&  352 &   198 \\
S132\_002\_00000018     &&  267 &   200 &&  352 &   199 \\
S132\_003\_00000023     &&  266 &   199 &&  352 &   198 \\
S132\_005\_00000016     &&  259 &   202 &&  350 &   200 \\
S132\_006\_00000023     &&  264 &   199 &&  352 &   199 \\
S132\_008\_00000010     &&  264 &   199 &&  349 &   197 \\
S133\_003\_00000001     &&  262 &   233 &&  362 &   231 \\
S133\_003\_00000047     &&  263 &   238 &&  361 &   234 \\
S133\_009\_00000006     &&  263 &   231 &&  363 &   226 \\
S133\_010\_00000014     &&  262 &   230 &&  363 &   227 \\
S134\_003\_00000001     &&  265 &   188 &&  362 &   189 \\
S134\_003\_00000011     &&  265 &   191 &&  360 &   191 \\
S134\_004\_00000015     &&  264 &   187 &&  362 &   189 \\
S134\_008\_00000013     &&  263 &   203 &&  363 &   204 \\
S135\_001\_00000001     &&  236 &   213 &&  335 &   212 \\
S135\_001\_00000039     &&  239 &   209 &&  334 &   208 \\
S135\_012\_00000020     &&  239 &   210 &&  332 &   210 \\
S136\_001\_00000001     &&  280 &   179 &&  373 &   184 \\
S136\_001\_00000019     &&  277 &   182 &&  370 &   187 \\
S136\_003\_00000014     &&  277 &   177 &&  372 &   179 \\
S136\_005\_00000010     &&  279 &   176 &&  373 &   180 \\
S136\_006\_00000020     &&  278 &   180 &&  372 &   184 \\
S137\_001\_00000001     &&  245 &   212 &&  354 &   212 \\
S137\_001\_00000014     &&  245 &   206 &&  353 &   209 \\
S137\_005\_00000027     &&  245 &   211 &&  354 &   217 \\
S137\_011\_00000020     &&  239 &   211 &&  350 &   213 \\
S138\_001\_00000001     &&  253 &   183 &&  356 &   182 \\
S138\_001\_00000012     &&  252 &   184 &&  354 &   184 \\
S138\_004\_00000013     &&  257 &   178 &&  360 &   176 \\
S138\_005\_00000016     &&  252 &   189 &&  353 &   187 \\
S138\_007\_00000011     &&  255 &   190 &&  359 &   187 \\
S138\_008\_00000009     &&  257 &   192 &&  359 &   193 \\
S139\_002\_00000001     &&  213 &   237 &&  318 &   236 \\
S139\_002\_00000013     &&  214 &   237 &&  317 &   238 \\
S147\_002\_00000001     &&  270 &   209 &&  376 &   206 \\
S147\_002\_00000013     &&  269 &   213 &&  376 &   209 \\
S148\_002\_00000001     &&  216 &   167 &&  312 &   170 \\
S148\_002\_00000015     &&  216 &   168 &&  312 &   170 \\
S149\_002\_00000001     &&  260 &   192 &&  381 &   188 \\
S149\_002\_00000013     &&  261 &   192 &&  382 &   187 \\
S151\_002\_00000001     &&  195 &   210 &&  293 &   214 \\
S151\_002\_00000029     &&  197 &   211 &&  295 &   214 \\
S154\_002\_00000001     &&  226 &   177 &&  332 &   179 \\
S154\_002\_00000013     &&  226 &   178 &&  332 &   180 \\
S155\_002\_00000001     &&  206 &   219 &&  305 &   214 \\
S155\_002\_00000012     &&  207 &   217 &&  304 &   215 \\
S156\_002\_00000001     &&  253 &   202 &&  355 &   202 \\
S156\_002\_00000021     &&  252 &   203 &&  355 &   201 \\
S157\_002\_00000001     &&  251 &   193 &&  354 &   197 \\
S157\_002\_00000011     &&  251 &   193 &&  354 &   197 \\
S158\_002\_00000001     &&  207 &   183 &&  325 &   177 \\
S158\_002\_00000011     &&  206 &   186 &&  323 &   180 \\
S160\_006\_00000001     &&  233 &   183 &&  335 &   180 \\
S160\_006\_00000010     &&  231 &   185 &&  337 &   181 \\
S501\_001\_00000001     &&  314 &   238 &&  444 &   234 \\
S501\_001\_00000067     &&  318 &   238 &&  448 &   236 \\
S501\_004\_00000056     &&  304 &   220 &&  443 &   218 \\
S501\_006\_00000041     &&  306 &   236 &&  437 &   231 \\
S502\_001\_00000001     &&  289 &   216 &&  418 &   217 \\
S502\_001\_00000016     &&  294 &   236 &&  421 &   239 \\
S502\_002\_00000009     &&  286 &   231 &&  413 &   230 \\
S502\_004\_00000052     &&  279 &   210 &&  403 &   208 \\
S503\_001\_00000001     &&  235 &   226 &&  383 &   225 \\
S503\_001\_00000071     &&  253 &   229 &&  384 &   225 \\
S503\_002\_00000008     &&  281 &   231 &&  409 &   227 \\
S503\_006\_00000020     &&  254 &   230 &&  384 &   229 \\
S504\_001\_00000001     &&  257 &   221 &&  393 &   223 \\
S504\_001\_00000022     &&  261 &   220 &&  398 &   221 \\
S504\_002\_00000009     &&  252 &   217 &&  385 &   216 \\
S504\_004\_00000015     &&  260 &   213 &&  395 &   215 \\
S504\_006\_00000018     &&  259 &   220 &&  394 &   220 \\
S505\_002\_00000001     &&  226 &   224 &&  364 &   223 \\
S505\_002\_00000021     &&  225 &   225 &&  363 &   225 \\
S505\_006\_00000019     &&  227 &   226 &&  364 &   224 \\
S506\_001\_00000001     &&  259 &   210 &&  388 &   210 \\
S506\_001\_00000040     &&  261 &   227 &&  394 &   227 \\
S506\_002\_00000009     &&  263 &   206 &&  386 &   204 \\
S506\_004\_00000038     &&  261 &   207 &&  383 &   208 \\
S506\_006\_00000042     &&  264 &   200 &&  391 &   199 \\
S895\_002\_00000001     &&  234 &   191 &&  332 &   180 \\
S895\_002\_00000007     &&  234 &   191 &&  334 &   181 \\
S999\_001\_00000001     &&  202 &   226 &&  309 &   224 \\
S999\_001\_00000018     &&  203 &   231 &&  311 &   230 \\
S999\_003\_00000055     &&  191 &   218 &&  300 &   216 \\

\bottomrule
\label{tab:eyeLabels}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

Sorry for putting the whole table, but that is the size of my table !!!

Comment: Similar: [How to solve longtable is not in 1-column mode error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161455)

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `xtabular` environment, provided by the [xtab](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtab) package, instead of the `longtable` environment. The upper portion of the first page would look like this:

[image]

In the code below, I've left out most of the table's rows to economize on space.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\small
\topcaption{A really long table }
\label{tab:eyeLabels}
\tablefirsthead{%
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Left Eye}} 
&& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Right Eye}}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    \textbf{Subject} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} 
                     && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\
\midrule}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Left Eye}} 
&& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Right Eye}}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    \textbf{Subject} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} 
                     && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\
\midrule}
\tabletail{\bottomrule}
\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
S005\_001\_00000001 &&  308 &   200 &&  431 &   196 \\
S005\_001\_00000011 &&  299 &   199 &&  439 &   193 \\
S010\_002\_00000001 &&  312 &   224 &&  436 &   222 \\
S010\_002\_00000014 &&  316 &   219 &&  437 &   217 \\
S010\_004\_00000001 &&  310 &   224 &&  433 &   220 \\
S010\_004\_00000019 &&  313 &   225 &&  432 &   220 \\
S010\_006\_00000001 &&  312 &   223 &&  435 &   217 \\
...
S999\_001\_00000018 &&  203 &   231 &&  311 &   230 \\
S999\_003\_00000055 &&  191 &   218 &&  300 &   216 \\
\end{xtabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you trick `longtable` that it is not inside a `multicols` enviroment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\scriptsize
\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne
\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Left Eye}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Right Eye}}\\
\cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(r){6-7}
\textbf{Subject} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} && \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\
\midrule

stuff removed

\bottomrule
\label{tab:eyeLabels}
\end{longtable}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}

\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45980/balancing-long-table-inside-multicol-in-latex) for more details; note that at least when I ran it you had overlap; margins may have to be modified, or you could [switch to landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode) for those pages.

Comment: Yeah ! It is working perfectly fine, but for one problem. The table is starting from first column of page 1 and then directly going to  first column of page 2, and then second column of page 2, and so on... I am wondering why it is not continuing from first column in page 1 to second column in page 1, instead of directly jumping to first column of page 2.