# Can a complex long table span over multiple pages with header in a two column article?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, two-column

I am writting a paper using latex for the first time, and I have a complex and long table that exceeds the page length. So I want to span the table over multiple pages with the header to be repeated. Also i see some examples that using the longtable package, but my latex template is in two column mode, in addition, I don't have enough experience in latex.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
%Table 1
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{head 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{head 1}} & \textbf{head 1} & \textbf{head 1} & \textbf{head 1} & \textbf{head 1} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{6}[12]{*}{2} & \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{12}[24]{*}{4} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{4}[8]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{4}[8]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{4}[8]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{18}[36]{*}{6} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{12}[24]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{4-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{6}[12]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{24}[48]{*}{8 Data} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{16}[32]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 6 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 7 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{4-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{\textbf{Data}} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 6 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       & Data 7 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{8}[16]{*}{\textbf{Data}}} & \multirow{8}[16]{*}{3000} & Data 0 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 1 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 2 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 3 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 4 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 5 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 6 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
\cline{6-8}          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       & Data 7 & 1000  & 2000 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can a long table span over multiple pages with header in a two column article?
Basically yes, [using the `supertabular` package and environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161455/110998). However, you use multirow cells, which makes it difficult/impossible to introduce row breaks automatically.

Two suggestions:

- Split the table into two or more.
- Use a smaller font size for the table. However, if you don't split the table, you need `\tiny`, which makes the table fit into one column, but makes it hard to read.