# Package longtable error: longtable not in 1-column mode. \begin{longtable}

Tags: longtable

I am trying to construct a longtable using the format below, but I kept having this error

```
Package longtable error: longtable not in 1-column mode. \begin{longtable}
```

Comment: you are presumably in two column, and as the error says, that isn't supported by longtable.  You could put `\onecolumn` before the table

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please can you elaborate on this? The document i am writing is two column/page.

Comment: you need to not use longtable (eg use xtab instead) or you need to switch to `\onecolumn` for the table and `\twocolumn` again afterwards.

Comment: But my table is long as well as will have to be in landscape position because of the content

Comment: xtab does multi-page tables, but if the table is so wide that you need it landscae then you persumably _want_ to switch to one column for the table, otherwise you have to squessze it in to half the width, also the lscape package also only works in single column.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle your intervention. It's of great help. I'm sorted!

Comment: Please check this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161455