# How to add a table in a landscape page into a two-columns layout?

Tags: tables, two-column, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I'm trying to add a landscape page with a table like in the figure. The table should stretch over the whole page and accommodate multiple lines of text.

I've looked at previous answers ( [1][1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode)) but I'm not sure how to integrate those answers in a two-column layout.

```
        % Contact: Holm Smidt, hsmidt@hawaii.edu
        %% Based on the style files for ACL 2015 by 
        %% car@ir.hit.edu.cn, gdzhou@suda.edu.cn

        \documentclass[10pt]{article}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{hicss51}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

        \newcommand{\sansserifformat}[1]{\fontfamily{cmss}{ #1}}

        \title{Please Read Carefully Detailed Formatting Guidelines for Preparing Your HICSS Final Paper with Author Names}

        \author{First Author \\
          Affiliation \\
          {\underline{ email@domain}} \\\And
          Second Author \\
          Affiliation \\
          {\underline{ email@domain} }\\}

        \begin{document}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]

        \end{abstract}

    \section{table}

    \section{table}

    \afterpage{%
        \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
        \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
            \centering % Center table
            \begin{tabular}{llll}
                This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text \\
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
        \end{landscape}
        \clearpage% Flush page
    }

        \section{Introduction}
        \lipsum[1-2]

        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{sample}


        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to put that as a table? It looks like something which would be better described just in text, imho.

Comment: @Skillmon It's my first time using Latex so I'm not sure it's a good idea. I just assumed it would be easier to reproduce what I posted in the image as a table, but I would welcome different approaches as well as long as the output is similar.

Comment: What I meant was to not output something similar, as a table with so much text could as well just be text without any table-like arrangement. What is the big problem you have? Do you fail to create such a table in general, or just placing it landscape? Can you please specify your question?

Comment: @Skillmon I fail to create a landscape page that ignores the 2-cols format (which is the layout I'm using). Regarding reason for using a table: In my case, a table just makes the content more readable.

Comment: In that case could you please add the table to your MWE? That might be more effort on your end, but it helps *everyone* willing to help you.

Comment: What is the `hicss51-packages.tex` file? I don't have it on my machine.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry I've substituted with the packages being imported from that file

Comment: Also the package `hicss51` is unknown to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this works with `hicss51` because I don't have that file, but you can use `\onecolumn` to switch to one column mode, and `\twocolumn` to switch back. Both introduce a `\clearpage`. I also used `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\input{hicss51-packages.tex}
\newcommand{\sansserifformat}[1]{\fontfamily{cmss}{ #1}}

\title{Please Read Carefully Detailed Formatting Guidelines for Preparing Your HICSS Final Paper with Author Names}

\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation \\
  {\underline{ email@domain}} \\\and
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation \\
  {\underline{ email@domain} }\\}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\section{table}

\section{table}

\afterpage{%
    \onecolumn% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \begin{sidewaystable}% 
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{*4{p{.2\linewidth}}}
            This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text \\
            This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text This table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text & This table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of textThis table has a lot of text \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \twocolumn
}

    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{sample}


    \end{document}
```