# Printing tables over the whole page width in a two-column document

Tags: tables

Can you explain how to print a table over the whole page width when in two-column? Those tables print fine in single column format in any of these `h`,`b`,`t`,`p` placements. But not when I use two-columns.

Comment: Does using `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}` solve the problem?

Comment: For the title of the question, seems that you are looking for  the `table*` environment, but without a minimal working example code, and without an image showing the problem, is rather unclear. "Not fine in two columns" is not a precise description of the problem ... please explain.

Answer (score 1):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89463/197451

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10] % To create a random first page

\lipsum[1-3]

[Location of the table in source code]

\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

The table will be on the third page, you'd have to move it up the code to get it in 2nd page.

Further reading: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017)

Comment: Thanks, It did work.

Comment: @sufipeace if it helped you may like to accept the answer and/or upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jsbibra's answer, I would like to mention that the  `sttools` bundle has two useful packages for floats in two column mode:

- `stfloats`, which  enables dblfloats to use the  `[t]` or `[b]` placement optional argument and to appear on the same page where they are defined if they are defined on left column and enough  free place is available on the current column/page.
- `cuted` defines a `strip` environment, which enables you to place some material full width in two column mode. Using it, you can place (non-float) tabulars or graphics, using `\captionof{float type}{…}`  if you want to have a caption.