# Positioning double column table below single column tables

Tags: tables, two-column, columns

I am using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` for writing LaTeX.
I want to place the double column table `table*` below the single column tables `table` on the top of document like this.

[image]

I have read several articles that the only available options for `table*` are `t` (top of next page) or `p` (end of document. [Page-wide table in two-column mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode)

So, I guess I need to find alternative way to represent the double column table `table*`.
Is there any other way that I can get the placement of tables like above?

Comment: put all three in the same `table*` (not related but `p` does not mean end of document, but float page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already suggested in a comment, you could place all three tables in a single `table*` environment. In the following code, the tables and their associated `\caption` statements are "wrapped" in `minipage` environments. The three tables employ `tabularx` environments with overall width `\linewidth`, to assure that they occupy the full width of the enclosing `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
%% first minipage
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\caption{Single-column wide}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%% second minipage % observe: no blank line above this line
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\caption{Single-column wide}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip 
%% third minipage
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{Double-column wide}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
\hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!! I sincerely appreciate it!